# The used range is not synced in the Microsoft Excel API after pushing data continuously in the Excel sheet

Tags: excel, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365, office365api

We are using two apis for pushing a row of data in the last. First we are using [getUsedRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/worksheet-usedrange?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request) for get used range of the worksheet and then we use worksheet's [rowsBelow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/workbookrange-rowsbelow?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request) api to push a row in last.

`PATCH - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{itemId}/workbook/Worksheets/{worksheetId}/range(address='A1:D13')/rowsBelow(count=1)`

Example: Initially, the used range in the given Excel sheet is A1:D13. After pushing a row in the sheet, we got the pushed response for the A14:D14 range . but in the used range API, we got the old used range. Due to this issue, the second request has been updated in the A13:D13 range.

Comment: Do you use workbook session? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/workbook-createsession?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: after using workbook session, the problem has been resolved